# Not getting issue in SonarQube Dashboard and removed existing analysis_options.yaml

Tags: flutter, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have installed this plugin in my sonarqube and set the proper configurations in project.

After I have run this command: "sonar-scanner.bat"

```
    19:23:00.667 INFO: Running 'flutter.bat [analyze, --no-fatal-warnings, --no-fatal-infos]'
    19:23:16.601 INFO: Command 'flutter.bat analyze --no-fatal-warnings --no-fatal-infos' finished (exit 0)
    19:23:16.604 DEBUG: Cleaned up temporary analysis_options.yaml file
    19:23:16.949 INFO: Recording 14168 issues
    19:23:16.950 DEBUG: Recording issue for analysis_options.yaml
    19:23:16.950 WARN: File not included in SonarQube analysis_options.yaml
    19:23:16.951 DEBUG: Recording issue for analysis_options.yaml
    19:23:16.951 WARN: File not included in SonarQube analysis_options.yaml
    19:23:16.951 DEBUG: Recording issue for analysis_options.yaml
    19:23:16.951 WARN: File not included in SonarQube analysis_options.yaml
    19:23:16.969 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.974 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.974 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.975 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.975 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.976 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.976 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.976 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.977 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.977 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.977 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.977 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.978 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.978 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.978 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.979 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.979 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.980 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.981 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.982 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.983 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:16.983 DEBUG: Recording issue for customer_controller.dart
    19:23:21.679 INFO: Sensor Dart analysis sensor [flutter] (done) | time=21205ms
    19:23:21.679 INFO: Sensor Flutter unit tests [flutter]
    19:23:21.681 INFO: Sensor Flutter unit tests [flutter] (done) | time=2ms
    19:23:21.681 INFO: Sensor Flutter Coverage [flutter]
    19:23:21.681 WARN: No coverage information will be saved because LCOV file cannot be found or read.
    19:23:21.681 WARN: Provided LCOV file path: coverage/lcov.info. Seek file with path: coverage\lcov.info
    19:23:21.682 INFO: Analysing [null]
    19:23:21.686 INFO: Sensor Flutter Coverage [flutter] (done) | time=5ms
    19:23:21.686 INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
    19:23:21.691 INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=5ms
    19:23:21.691 INFO: Sensor TextAndSecretsSensor [text]
    19:23:22.374 INFO: 189 source files to be analyzed
    19:23:25.297 INFO: 189/189 source files have been analyzed
    19:23:25.297 INFO: Sensor TextAndSecretsSensor [text] (done) | time=3606ms
    19:23:25.297 INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet]
    19:23:25.299 INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet] (done) | time=2ms
    19:23:25.299 INFO: Sensor VB.NET Analysis Log [vbnet]
    19:23:25.317 DEBUG: Project '': Property missing: 'sonar.vbnet.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
    19:23:25.317 INFO: Sensor VB.NET Analysis Log [vbnet] (done) | time=18ms
    19:23:25.317 INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet]
    19:23:25.318 DEBUG: Project '': Property missing: 'sonar.vbnet.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
    19:23:25.318 DEBUG: Project '': No Roslyn issues reports have been found.
    19:23:25.318 INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet] (done) | time=1ms
    19:23:25.318 INFO: Sensor IaC Docker Sensor [iac]
    19:23:25.322 INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
    19:23:25.432 INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
    19:23:25.432 INFO: Sensor IaC Docker Sensor [iac] (done) | time=114ms
    19:23:25.437 INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
    19:23:25.566 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
    19:23:25.567 DEBUG: 'Import external issues report from SARIF file.' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
    19:23:25.567 DEBUG: 'C#' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.568 DEBUG: 'C# File Caching Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.569 DEBUG: 'C# Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.569 DEBUG: '[Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.570 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.570 DEBUG: 'VB.NET' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.571 DEBUG: 'VB.NET File Caching Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.572 DEBUG: 'VB.NET Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.573 DEBUG: '[Deprecated] VB.NET Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.574 DEBUG: 'VB.NET Unit Test Results Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.574 DEBUG: 'Java CPD Block Indexer' skipped because there is no related file in current project
    19:23:25.574 DEBUG: Sensors : Analysis Warnings import -> Zero Coverage Sensor
    19:23:25.575 INFO: Sensor Analysis Warnings import [csharp]
    19:23:25.578 INFO: Sensor Analysis Warnings import [csharp] (done) | time=3ms
    19:23:25.578 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
    19:23:25.583 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=5ms
    19:23:25.777 INFO: CPD Executor 5 files had no CPD blocks
    19:23:25.777 INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 184 files
    19:23:25.777 DEBUG: Detection of duplications for order_controller.dart
    19:23:25.791 DEBUG: Detection of duplications for standard_response_model.dart
    19:23:26.094 INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=316ms
    19:23:26.121 DEBUG: SCM revision ID '9eee0ef711a657a1831cb'
    19:23:34.275 INFO: Analysis report generated in 554ms, dir size=1.4 MB
    19:23:35.047 INFO: Analysis report compressed in 747ms, zip size=485.9 kB
    19:23:35.048 INFO: Analysis report generated in .scannerwork\scanner-report
    19:23:35.048 DEBUG: Upload report
    19:23:35.121 DEBUG: POST 200 http://localhost:4005 | time=71ms
    19:23:35.132 INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 80ms
    19:23:35.135 DEBUG: Report metadata written to .scannerwork\report-task.txt
    19:23:35.135 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can find the results at: http://localhost:4005/
    19:23:35.135 INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
    19:23:35.135 INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:4005/api/
    19:23:35.147 DEBUG: Post-jobs :
    19:23:35.159 INFO: Analysis total time: 55.532 s
    19:23:35.164 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    19:23:35.165 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
    19:23:35.165 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    19:23:35.165 INFO: Total time: 1:00.645s
    19:23:35.265 INFO: Final Memory: 27M/108M
    19:23:35.266 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In flutter.bat analyze I am getting the errors but after success when I checked into the sonarqube not get any error can you please help with it?

Thanks

List the issue on sonarque dashboard.